# How to format the output of the jot command

Tags: macos, shell

I have a very simple command `jot -r 4 0 255` which basically output 4 random numbers in the range from 0 to 255.

```
> jot -r 4 0 255
66
14
244
155
```

How can I format the output to something like this: `66.14.244.155`?

Answer (score 2):

Use a period character as a separator string between the results of the `jot` command. Open the terminal and type:

```
jot -s "." 4 0 255
```

From the results of `man jot` :

```
-s string
        Print data separated by string. Normally, newlines separate data.
```

In some other cases a space character would make a good separator string.

Comment: That was easy... I had an idea to use bash & read, I'll still post it anyway I guess

Answer (score 0):

I made a test file, `t` containing similar output

```
$ cat t
66
14
244
155
```

There's a bunch of different ways to reformat output, piped from any command or `cat` like these examples:

- use bash's `read` like this

  ```
  $ cat t | while read i; do echo -n "$i."; done; echo
  66.14.244.155.
  ```

  to read each entry & echo it with a trailing dot & no newline (adding a plain echo at the end to get a trailing newline).
- `tr`anslate each newline into a dot, again with a trailing dot & no newline

  ```
  $ cat t | tr '\n' '.'
  66.14.244.155.
  ```
- the same but with a very short `awk`

  ```
  $ cat t | tr '\n' '.' | awk 'ORS="."'
  66.14.244.155.
  ```
- `tr` (or `awk`) again, but fix the trailing dot into a newline

  ```
  $ cat t | tr '\n' '.' | sed 's/.$/\n/'
  66.14.244.155
  ```
- all `sed` that's [apparently faster & less complex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48486375/3412074) with no trailing dot and a newline

  ```
  $ cat t | sed -e ':a; N; $!ba; s/\n/./g'
  66.14.244.155
  ```
- `paste` can use it's `s`erial & `d`elimiter options, with no trailing dot and a newline

  ```
  $ cat t | paste -sd "." -
  66.14.244.155
  ```

<sub>[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48486375/3412074)</sub>

Comment: Even without `jot -s`, there's no need to `read` in a loop. Just use `tr` or `paste`, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764051/how-to-join-multiple-lines-of-file-names-into-one-with-custom-delimiter)

Comment: @dirkt If there isn't a handful of different ways to do something, it's hardly worth doing